# CSS content floats on the different size screen.

Tags: css

CSS is giving me bit of headache. I have this format for my page and would like to add contents to the center. I have problem with content moving or floating depending on the screen size, It looks great on my screen, but on someone who has wide screen this looks different. Any suggestion and assistance will be appreciated.

```
#navcontainer { 
  width: 150px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-top:auto;
}           
 #navcontainer ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;


}
#navcontainer a:link, #navlist a:visited {
  color: #2200CC;
  text-decoration: none;
  display:block;
  height:30px;
}
#navcontainer a:hover {
  background-color: #369;
  color: #fff;
  display:block;
  height:30px;
}
#navcontainer {
  font-family: verdana,tahoma,helvetica;
  font-size: 10pt;
  background-color: #99CCFF;
  border-top-width: 0;
  border: solid 3px #d7d7d7;
  border-top-color: #99CC66;
  margin-left: 10pt;
  float:left;
  margin-top:-22px;
  padding-left:20px; 
}
#navcontainer #selected a {
  background-color: white;
  color:Black;
}
.basictab {
  padding: 3px 0;
  margin-left: 189px;
  font: bold 12px Verdana;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left; /*set to left, center, or right to align the menu as desired*/
}
.basictab li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
}
.basictab li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 3px 7px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-bottom: none;
  background-color: #f6ffd5;
  color: #2d2b2b;
}
.basictab li a:visited{
  color: #2d2b2b;
}
.basictab li a:hover{
  background-color: #DBFF6C;
  color: black;
}
.basictab li a:active{
  color: black;
}
.basictab li.selected a{ /*selected tab effect*/
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  background-color: #DBFF6C;
  color: black;
}
body {
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-family:"Adobe Garamond Pro Bold", Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #061C37;
}
* {
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  text-align:left;      
} 
.contentBox {
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
  margin-top:10px;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    margin-left:210px;
    margin-top:-400px;
} 
.contentBox .innerBox {

  height:auto;
  top:10px;
  margin-left:10px;
  padding-bottom:35px;
}
#GridView1 {
  margin-left:130px;  
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TMKev/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use media queries to target different screen sizes.
See http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-a-crash-course-in-css-media-queries/

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about a fixed width for your overall page that centers in the screen?

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 960px;  
}

.sidecol {
  background: #ccc;
  margin-right: 2%;
  width: 18%;
}

.main-content {
  background: #efefef;
  width: 80%;
}

.sidecol, .main-content {
  float: left;
  height: 400px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <aside class="sidecol">
    <h3>My sidebar</h3>
  </aside>
  <section class="main-content">
    <h3>Content</h3>
    <p> My content</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

[Codepen sketch](http://cdpn.io/mIdaJ)